# Kotlin `with` with multiple params

Tags: kotlin

I really like how `with` behaves. Is it possible to extend `with` so it works with multiple params.

I want to use `with` like this.

```
with(foo, bar){
    fooFunction()
    barFunction()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I strongly against it.

One can come close to what you want:

```
data class A(val a: Int)
data class B(val b: Int)

fun<S, T> withPair(a: S, b: T, f: S.() -> T.() -> Unit) {
    val g = a.f()
    b.g()
}

fun main() {
    withPair(A(1), B(2)) {{
        print(a)
        print(b)
    }}
}
```

So you can have a block function which return a block function. You need nested lambdas though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to write a function which behaves like this, but with the standard `with` you *can* write

```
with(foo) {
    with(bar) {
        fooFunction()
        barFunction()
    }
}
```

(note that if a method is available on both `foo` and `bar`, this way the `bar` method will be called).

Comment: Yeah, nesting gives pretty much the same effect.  Of course, the potential ambiguity is dangerous: as you say, with nesting, members of `bar` will get priority, whereas with a combined version you'd probably get a compile-time error.  But that apart, there's probably no need for new syntax.  (Especially as it would probably need deep changes to the language to change the name resolution.)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use a `Pair`,  something like:

```
with( Pair("abc" , listOf(1,2,3)) ) {
    println(first.plus("d"))
    println(second.reversed())
}
```

Prints:

abcd
   [3, 2, 1]

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to do this with the standard `with` function because it cannot have two receiver types of the lambda (accessed by `this`).

```
with(foo, bar){
    fooFunction() //`this` would have to mean `foo`
    barFunction() //`this` would have to mean `bar`
}
```

Nesting two `with`s is nasty. It can cause all sort of issues, with `this` ambiguity...

---

That said, you can create your own `with` function that will work similarly to the standard one, but will not use passed extension fun (so no receiver type "hidden" behind `this`), but a regular lambda with two arguments:

```
inline fun <T1, T2, R> with(t1: T1, t2: T2, block: (T1, T2) -> R): R {
    return block.invoke(t1, t2)
}

//then:
with(foo, bar) { f, b ->
    f.fooFunction()
    b.barFunction()
}
```